# I need assistance converting thermostats from a Honeywell RTH2300B1012 to Honeywell RTH5160D1003

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, furnace, air-conditioning

I currently have a home with 3 zones and a central A/C and oil-fired forced hot air.  The way the system has always worked in the main stat has to be set to heating or cooling for the others to run heating or cooling as well. A few years ago, the local HVAC company replaced the stat with the RTH2300B1012 after the original died.  It was set to Oil heat on the stat and wired as follows (image[image: Old Wiring]):

- Blue Wire to B Pin
- Red Wire labeled O to O Pin (Voltmeter check has this run to equipment panel)
- Green Wire to G Pin
- Yellow Wire to Y Pin
- White Wire to W Pin
- Red Wire labeled R to R Pin (Voltmeter check has this run to second floor stat)
- Jumper from R Pin to Rc Pin

The furnace is wired from the stat to the equipment group as such ([image: Equipment Panel]):

- Blue Wire to C Pin
- Red Wire labeled O to R Pin
- White Wire to W Pin
- Yellow Wire to Y Pin
- Green Wire to G Pin

I'm trying to figure out how to best wire and configure the replacement RTH5160D1003 thermostat.  Image attached shows the wiring I have with the Red line labeled O to the O pin.[image: New Thermostat Wiring] That is for heat pump **only** however but it does fire the house fan when it calls for heat.  I was told by Honeywell support that a physical jumper isn't needed if the cover below the R pin is in the 1 wire configuration, thus acting like a jumper.  They also said the 'orange' wire isn't necessary and should be tied off, but they didn't know that wire was firing the equipment.  Keep in mind the newer unit has a ton of configuration options within the stat too. Any guidance is most appreciated in getting this working.  I also still have the old unit if all else fails, I just prefer the look of the new one.
Thanks!
David

Comment: I crossed wires when installing the t-stat for my new 97% ECM-motor furnace and it stopped working and my heart sank very low. Luckily it only blew a fuse on the mainboard; thank goodness it wasn't worse. **You** need to read and understand the wiring instructions for the t-stat, furnace, and A/C if you wish to avoid the heart-in-stomach feeling. Best of luck to you.

Comment: What make and model is your zone board? That's going to be *absolutely critical* here

Comment: Thanks Monkey.... Really, thanks.  Anyway, it's a Durazone SMZ-SW.  I traced out the lines from each thermostat to the control board and it looks like they're all wired properly based on the schematic in the control board manual.  It looks like it's pointing to a wiring in the main thermostat (zone 1) and perhaps a configuration in that thermostat.  The newer stat, although it's non-programmable, is a little more in-depth on the configuration side.  I'm having difficulty figuring out where the O wire goes in the new stat and how to configure it properly for an oil-fired furnace and AC system

Comment: After reaching out to the control board manufacturer, I found that because the board is about 30 years old, I will need to wire in a 24VAC relay to be compatible with these.new ahe thermostats. I have the relay ordered and will report my findings